# Getting Facebook to recognize params for OpenGraph

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, parameters

I have a dynamic script set up for user submissions, each image they submit has the trailing URL of **/image.php?id=150** or something similar.

I need Facebook to recognize a param.

If I copy and past the URL **http://mysite.com/image.php?id=150** it doesn't recognize the id=150, just the image.php, making it impossible to be able to paste and receive thumbnails, descriptions, titles, and whatever else via the OG: meta tags.

Basically I need Facebook to recognize **/image.php?id=150** and **/image.php?id=151** as 2 different URLs, rather then the same so that they can have their own dynamic meta tags and therefor have their own thumbnails, descriptions, and whatever else when posted to Facebook.

Any help at all would be appreciated, I am having real trouble with this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond Facebook graph API but it might help you,
create a permalink for each Image using .htaccess

```
Allow from All
RewriteEngine on

SetEnv DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT true

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ image.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That will make your URL cleaner so the new URL to share is `http://mysite.com/150` instead of yours
and you might want to use a sub-folder like `photo` so it would be like `http://mysite.com/photo/150` and copy image.php to that Dir